# How to split long commands over multiple lines in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

How do you take a command like the following in PowerShell and split it across multiple lines?

```
&"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:contentPath="c:\workspace\xxx\master\Build\_PublishedWebsites\xxx.Web" -dest:contentPath="c:\websites\xxx\wwwroot\,computerName=192.168.1.1,username=administrator,password=xxx"
```

Comment: See also ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter a multi-line command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command)

Answer (score 512, accepted):

Trailing backtick character, i.e.,

```
&"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" `
-verb:sync `
-source:contentPath="c:\workspace\xxx\master\Build\_PublishedWebsites\xxx.Web" `
-dest:contentPath="c:\websites\xxx\wwwroot,computerName=192.168.1.1,username=administrator,password=xxx"
```

White space matters. The required format is <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>`</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This seems to break command history (up arrow) functionality; as each line shows up as a separate command. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you're running powershell 3 or higher, see github.com/lzybkr/psreadline - history traversal is fixed for multiline statements.

Comment: The space in front of the back-tick is required #learned-the-hard-way

Comment: @josh-graham And there should NOT be any space (or inline comment) AFTER the back-tick. #learned-the-hard-way

Comment: Backticks are brittle (as above comments state) and hard to find when parsing or reviewing a file. @StevenPenny 's answer is better if you want easier to debug code.

Comment: You can also split the strings over multiple lines with the subexpression and arithmetic operators $() and +. e.g. -dest:contentPath=$("c:\websites\xxx\wwwroot," + 
"computerName=192.168.1.1" +
...). A new line can follow each +.

Comment: For curious like me: Powershell's official doc, page about_Parsing, sec _Line Continuation_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.3#line-continuation .

Comment: backtick is not really a good practice, since any invisible character after it breaks the code

Answer (score 93):

Another method for cleaner argument passing would be [splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx).

Define your parameters and values as a hashtable like this:

```
$params = @{ 'class' = 'Win32_BIOS';
             'computername'='SERVER-R2';
             'filter'='drivetype=3';
             'credential'='Administrator' }
```

And then call your commandlet like this:

```
Get-WmiObject @params
```

Microsoft Docs: [About Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)

TechNet Magazine 2011: [Windows PowerShell: Splatting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg675931.aspx)

[Looks like it works with Powershell 2.0 and up](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts.aspx)

Comment: This is wonderful!  AND you can add parameters like this:  `$params.add('name','Bob Newhart')`   https://ramblingcookiemonster.wordpress.com/2014/12/01/powershell-splatting-build-parameters-dynamically/

Comment: The semicolons are ok but superfluous. Only required if there are multiple values per line.

Comment: This doesn't work for normal shell command, mainly for PowerShell commandlets

Comment: This should be the new accepted answer. Splatting is a very standard thing to do nowadays.

Answer (score 47):

Ah, and if you have a very long string that you want to break up, say of HTML, you can do it by putting a `@` on each side of the outer `"` - like this:

```
$mystring = @"
Bob
went
to town
to buy
a fat
pig.
"@
```

You get exactly this:

```
Bob
went
to town
to buy
a fat
pig.
```

And if you are using [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), it will even highlight correctly as a string block.

Now, if you wanted that string to contain double quotes, too, just add them in, like this:

```
$myvar = "Site"
$mystring = @"
<a href="http://somewhere.com/somelocation">
Bob's $myvar
</a>
"@
```

You would get exactly this:

```
<a href="http://somewhere.com/somelocation">
Bob's Site
</a>
```

However, if you use double-quotes in that @-string like that, Notepad++ doesn't realize that and will switch out the syntax colouring as if it were not quoted or quoted, depending on the case.

And what's better is this: anywhere you insert a $variable, it DOES get interpreted! (If you need the dollar sign in the text, you escape it with a tick mark like this: ``$not-a-variable`.)

NOTICE! If you don't put the final `"@` at the *very start of the line*, it will fail. It took me an hour to figure out that I could not indent that in my code!

Here is [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network) on the subject: *[Using Windows PowerShell “Here-Strings”](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee692792.aspx?ppud=4)*

Comment: Neat trick, though if I have a variable $... it seems to not work. I get "the character is not allowed after a here string header..."

Comment: I don't think you can break a variable name, just a string.

Comment: Can you break the string in the source without having the new line characters figure in the result? Like an argument list.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the backtick operator:

```
& "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" `
    -verb:sync `
    -source:contentPath="c:\workspace\xxx\master\Build\_PublishedWebsites\xxx.Web" `
    -dest:contentPath="c:\websites\xxx\wwwroot\,computerName=192.168.1.1,username=administrator,password=xxx"
```

That's still a little too long for my taste, so I'd use some well-named variables:

```
$msdeployPath = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe"
$verbArg = '-verb:sync'
$sourceArg = '-source:contentPath="c:\workspace\xxx\master\Build\_PublishedWebsites\xxx.Web"'
$destArg = '-dest:contentPath="c:\websites\xxx\wwwroot\,computerName=192.168.1.1,username=administrator,password=xxx"'

& $msdeployPath $verbArg $sourceArg $destArg
```

Comment: I like variable names over other suggestions because it's possibly the most readable option for non powershell experts. If I saw a tutorial/set-up guide that used splatting I would be totally lost at what is going on without a sub-tutorial on splatting. Likewise, backticks seem fragile and probably less well known than simple tried and true PS variables.

Answer (score 19):

If you have a function:

```lisp
$function:foo | % Invoke @(
  'bar'
  'directory'
  $true
)
```

If you have a [cmdlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell#Cmdlets):

```lisp
[PSCustomObject] @{
  Path  = 'bar'
  Type  = 'directory'
  Force = $true
} | New-Item
```

If you have an application:

```lisp
{foo.exe @Args} | % Invoke @(
  'bar'
  'directory'
  $true
)
```

Or

```lisp
icm {foo.exe @Args} -Args @(
  'bar'
  'directory'
  $true
)
```

Answer (score 7):

In PowerShell 5 and PowerShell 5 ISE, it is also possible to use just <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> for multiline editing (instead of standard backticks `` ` `` at the end of each line):

```
PS> &"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy\msdeploy.exe" # Shift+Enter
>>> -verb:sync # Shift+Enter
>>> -source:contentPath="c:\workspace\xxx\master\Build\_PublishedWebsites\xxx.Web" # Shift+Enter
>>> -dest:contentPath="c:\websites\xxx\wwwroot,computerName=192.168.1.1,username=administrator,password=xxx"
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to break a string across multiple lines is to put an empty expression in the middle of the string, and break it across lines:

sample string:

`"stackoverflow stackoverflow stackoverflow stackoverflow stackoverflow"`

broken across lines:

```
"stackoverflow stackoverflow $(
)stackoverflow stack$(
)overflow stackoverflow"
```

Comment: This is so ugly! :) Still no better solution in 2023?

Comment: [this seems better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56492187/185123) but in the same vain: `$blah = ("blah" + " blah")`  @Lorlin

Answer (score 4):

**Splat Method with Calculations**

If you choose splat method, beware calculations that are made using other parameters.  In practice, sometimes I have to set variables first then create the hash table.  Also, the format doesn't require single quotes around the key value or the semi-colon (as mentioned above).

```
Example of a call to a function that creates an Excel spreadsheet

$title = "Cut-off File Processing on $start_date_long_str"
$title_row = 1
$header_row = 2
$data_row_start = 3
$data_row_end = $($data_row_start + $($file_info_array.Count) - 1)

# use parameter hash table to make code more readable
$params = @{
    title = $title
    title_row = $title_row
    header_row = $header_row
    data_row_start = $data_row_start
    data_row_end = $data_row_end
}
$xl_wksht = Create-Excel-Spreadsheet @params
```

Note: The file array contains information that will affect how the spreadsheet is populated.