# How to enter a multi-line command

Tags: powershell, multiline

Is it possible to split a PowerShell command line over multiple lines?

In Visual Basic I can use the underscore (`_`) to continue the command in the next line.

Comment: The "why not backslashes" question is covered nicely in Bruce Payette's _PowerShell in Action_; great book. Bruce has a broad knowledge of the history of programming languages. Looking forward to V2 of this book.

Comment: Duplicate of ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608144/how-to-split-long-commands-over-multiple-lines-in-powershell

Comment: Sorry if offtopic but if you are to submit the script with `sh` command, bash conventions hold so you can use backslash. In that case your script should also have unix style endings.

Comment: just use ` character to separate command on multiple lines

Answer (score 929, accepted):

You can use a space followed by the grave accent (backtick):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse `
  -Filter *.jpg `
  | Select LastWriteTime
```

However, this is only ever necessary in such cases as shown above. Usually you get automatic line continuation when a command cannot syntactically be complete at that point. This includes starting a new pipeline element:

```
Get-ChildItem |
  Select Name,Length
```

will work without problems since after the `|` the command cannot be complete since it's missing another pipeline element. Also opening curly braces or any other kind of parentheses will allow line continuation directly:

```
$x=1..5
$x[
  0,3
] | % {
  "Number: $_"
}
```

Similar to the `|` a comma will also work in some contexts:

```
1,
2
```

Keep in mind, though, similar to JavaScript's [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion), there are some things that are similarly broken because the line break occurs at a point where it *is* preceded by a valid statement:

```
return
  5
```

will not work.

Finally, strings (in all varieties) may also extend beyond a single line:

```
'Foo
bar'
```

They include the line breaks within the string, then.

Comment: You say "any other kind of parentheses will allow line continuation directly" but I needed the backtick for `$stream.WriteLine('foo'` *(newline here)* `+'bar')`.

Comment: @JackDouglas: You can have a line break directly *after* the opening parenthesis, but not within the expression before the operator, apparently. That being said, I believe that to be an oversight in the grammar.

Comment: Backtick does not  work for me, the command never goes out of the multiline mode.

Comment: Line continuation doesn't work in the ISE command pane, apparently.

Comment: This does not mean that if a cmdlet has further mandatory arguments,  powershell will look on the next line for them.  e.g.  `new-aduser <CR> username` does not work.

Comment: @Dan: There's a difference between a cmdlet having mandatory parameters (which is a semantic thing) and the grammar telling you that the pipeline is incomplete (which is a syntax thing). The parser only knows how cmdlets and parameters look like, but not whether they are mandatory or not. Line continuation happens in the parser.

Comment: Makes sense - just wasn't how I imagined it working when I read the answer, so I wanted to point it out for the next person.

Comment: Just a note if you use a backtick to end a line, there cannot be any characters between the backtick and the newline, not even a space.  Backtick escapes the next character, and if there's something between, then it won't escape the newline correctly.

Comment: @Ryan, as far as I know that's true in any language that has line continuation, so it didn't seem immigrant to mention it.

Comment: @Joey I only posted the comment because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11828731) is up for deletion in review (it should have originally been a comment), but clearly it was important to at least 20 people.

Comment: Seems like the `\\` concat lines in shell.

Answer (score 119):

There must not be **any** character between the backtick and the line break. Even whitespace will cause the command to not work.

Comment: While this is technically not the answer to the question, +1 because this is absolutely essential.  I just found this out the hard way, and will surely be avoiding the back-tick in future development wherever possible.

Comment: So there is essentially no robust way to break a long line in Powershell. No wonder I tend to see those [2-screen-wide powershell scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608144/how-to-split-long-commands-over-multiple-lines-in-powershell) every where. #ShakeMyHead

Comment: I was struggling with this, too... you can insert an inline comment before the back-tick to include a comment, like this: 

Some-Command `
    -arg1 <# explain arg 1 #> `
    -arg2 <# explain arg 2 #>

Comment: Urgh.  This makes PowerShell code unnecessarily difficult to post in documentation or websites, for fear that the command will either be read wrong by a human if using Shift+Enter, or parsed wrong in ISE's command line when using the back tick.

Comment: Down-vote due to the nature of the comment (which is not a complete answer to the original question).

Comment: **Technical Note** - this is because the backtick is *not* a line continuation operator per se; it's really an *escape* character that is serving to "escape" the newline at the end of the line.  If you enter a space after the backtick, it'll escape that instead of the newline character.  Further reading at [**Natural Line Continuations in PowerShell**](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html)

Comment: there's nothing strange in this. All C-like languages require the escape character to be immediately precede the new line without any whitespace in between. Of course that's because the escape is for escaping the new line and not the spaces

Comment: Also, make your file's newlines Unix, not Windows, because Windows linebreaks are two characters, and thus the backtick will only escape half the linebreak.

Comment: Hilarious but true!

Answer (score 44):

In most C-like languages I am deliberate about placing my braces where I think they make the code easiest to read.

PowerShell's parser recognizes when a statement clearly isn't complete, and looks to the next line. For example, imagine a cmdlet that takes an optional script block parameter:

```
    Get-Foo { ............ }
```

if the script block is very long, you might want to write:

```
    Get-Foo
    {
        ...............
        ...............
        ...............
    }
```

But this won't work: the parser will see two statements. The first is `Get-Foo` and the second is a script block. Instead, I write:

```
    Get-Foo {
        ...............
        ...............
        ...............
    }
```

I could use the line-continuation character (`) but that makes for hard-to-read code, and invites bugs.

Because this case requires the open brace to be on the previous line, I follow that pattern everywhere:

```
    if (condition) {
        .....
    }
```

> Note that `if` statements require a script block in the language grammar, so the parser will look on the next line for the script block, but for consistency, I keep the open brace on the same line.

Simlarly, in the case of long pipelines, I break after the pipe character (`|`):

```
    $project.Items | 
        ? { $_.Key -eq "ProjectFile" } | 
        % { $_.Value } | 
        % { $_.EvaluatedInclude } |
        % {
            .........
        }
```

Comment: how does `if` and `foreach` and `try` work then? they allow script blocks on the next line... this means it mut be possible

Comment: @Nacht: From rusty memory: statements that require a script block, per the language grammar, will parse past a newline to find one. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: @Nacht: "But this won't work" was referring to situations where the further parameters are optional, which is most cases.

Comment: ah i see what you mean now. so "if" and "foreach" are not actually cmdlets - they are actuall part of the grammar, thus forcing it to look past to the next line. is there then no way to let a user-defined function  read a script block from the next line? i suppose your above answer answers that question exactly.

Answer (score 35):

To expand on [cristobalito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235914):

> I assume you're talking about on the command-line - if it's in a script, then a new-line >acts as a command delimiter.
>
> On the command line, use a semi-colon ';'

For example:

Sign a PowerShell script on the command-line. No line breaks.

```
powershell -Command "&{$cert=Get-ChildItem –Path cert:\CurrentUser\my -codeSigningCert ; Set-AuthenticodeSignature -filepath Z:\test.ps1 -Cert $cert}
```

Comment: Not the answer to the question, but your answer answered my question. :)

Comment: That's interesting, but it's the opposite of what OP was asking. OP wanted to split a single command across several lines; you explained how to combine several commands onto one line.

Answer (score 23):

In PowerShell and PowerShell ISE, it is also possible to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of each line for multiline editing (instead of standard backtick `` ` ``).

Comment: This is a great tip for editing multi-line here-strings, which are otherwise horrible to edit if you don't know the `SHIFT-ENTER` trick.

Comment: I believe this is the case in the console version of PowerShell only when using the `PSReadLine` module or an equivalent. In the standard Windows console input functions, `Enter` and `Shift+Enter` are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart true, it works in the ISE console without PSReadline, but not in the Console Host.

Comment: To clarify: 1) The `PSReadline` module works in the console host _only_ (not ISE). 2) `Shift+Enter` works in the console host _only_ when using `PSReadline`. 3) `Shift+Enter` has always worked in the ISE. 4) If using the console host without `PSReadline`, `Shift+Enter` is functionally equivalent to pressing `Enter`.

Comment: this is the right answer, the one which is accepted and have 400 up-vote is very confusing and useless!!

Comment: But how do I then execute? After I created a new line with shift+enter a normal Enter will only create another line with "<<"

Answer (score 14):

Just add a corner case here. It might save you 5 minutes. If you use a chain of actions, you need to put "." at the end of line, leave a space followed by the "`" (backtick). I found this out the hard way.

```
$yourString = "HELLO world! POWERSHELL!". `
                  Replace("HELLO", "Hello"). `
                  Replace("POWERSHELL", "Powershell")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Tried to achieve this unsuccessfully for some time..

Comment: Seems to work without space and backtick as long as you put the dot on the previous line, even if there are spaces after it and before the subsequent method call. Even comments work, like `Replace("HELLO", "Hello").  # comment here`

Answer (score 12):

Just use `` ` `` character to separate command on multiline

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to separate strings into multiple lines, you can use the "+". For example:

```
$header =    "Make," +

             "ComputerName," +

             "Model," +

             "Windows Version"
```

Will look just like:

```
$header = "Make,ComputerName,Model,Windows Version"
```

Answer (score 4):

I started by doing

```
if ($true) {
"you can write multiple lines here, and the command doesn't run untill you close the bracket"

"like this"
}
```

Recently found out I could just

```
&{
get-date
"more stuff"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## This is an old post, so here's the modern method.

If you're not using legacy powershell, the cleanest way to continue lines is the `pipe` at the **start of the line**.

[image]

**Note:** The command doesn't break with some lines commented out. This is great on the command line.

```
> Get-ChildItem -path 'c:\' -Depth 1                 
    | Sort-Object LastWriteTime                       
    # | Sort-Object Length -Descending                   
    | Select-Object -First 3 -Skip 3                   
    | Foreach-Object {                                 
      $_.Name, $_.Length | Join-String -Separator ' = '                                                       
    }
```

output:

```
explorer.exe = 4826160                                 
procexp.old.exe = 2925760                              
RtlExUpd.dll = 2839488
```

## Windows Powershell ( Version < 6 )

Unfortunately windows powershell does not support it. A bunch of alternatives are linked above. You can remove the backtick completely: [2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html)

Comment: You're suggesting pipe, which is wrong answer. The correct answer is using  **backtick  `**  followed by newline.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, maybe I was ambiguous there. using `backtick` to escape a newline is what I meant by legacy version. Because that's a limitation for  `Windows Powershell` (`powershell.exe`) -- `Powershell` (`pwsh.exe`) added the pipe prefix as built in syntax. -- WinPs was end of life years ago, all development is  on `Pwsh`. You can install them side-by-side. ---- If you're using `WinPS`, check out that link above. .[remove-the-backtick](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html) . You can almost entirely eliminate the need for backticks

Comment: This only works if each new line is a new command. If it is multi-line, but each line is not a new command, then the pipe method does not work. Backtick is necessary there.

Comment: I'm trying to picture it, I'm not exactly sure what you mean, can you give an example?

Comment: He means if you want to split the input  parameters of a single command over multiple lines as opposed to multiple commands that pipe their input/output to each other

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're talking about on the command-line - if it's in a script, then a new-line acts as a command delimiter.

On the command line, use a semi-colon ';'

Answer (score 3):

1. Use a semi-colon `;` to separate command
2. Replace double backslash `\\` on any backslashes `\`.
3. Use `"'` for passing safe address to switch command like "'PATH'".

***This ps1 command install locale pfx certificate.***

```
powershell -Command "$pfxPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "12345678" -Force -AsPlainText ; Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "'C:\\Program Files\\VpnManagement\\resources\\assets\\cert\\localhost.pfx'" Cert:\\LocalMachine\\My -Password $pfxPassword ; Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath "'C:\\Program Files\\VpnManagement\\resources\\assets\\cert\\localhost.pfx'" Cert:\\LocalMachine\\Root -Password $pfxPassword"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's sooo many ways to continue a line in powershell, with pipes, brackets, parentheses, operators, dots, even with a comma.  Here's a blog about it:  https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html

You can continue right after statements like foreach and if as well.

Comment: A long but interesting article. Instead of escaping line breaks with backticks, one may use array splatting (even though the `@` splat operator doesn't seem to be necessary). For example: `$params = @( '-v', '-X', 'GET'); curl $params http://example.org`. Not `'-X GET'` but two separate elements are needed. And don't call the variable `$args`, it's reserved.

Comment: Or just a comma to continue.

Comment: Yeah, no splatting is actually required, but quotes are: `curl '-v', '-X', 'GET', 'http://example.org'`. The recommendation from the article is to use a variable with splatting for readability however. BTW: If written on a single line and if you remove the spaces between the arguments, then it suddenly break? `curl '-v','-X','GET','http://example.org'` - 
`curl: option -v,-X,GET,http://example.org: is unknown`. A single space between any of the arguments makes it work again.

Answer (score 2):

```
$scriptBlock = [Scriptblock]::Create(@'
  echo 'before'
  ipconfig /all
  echo 'after'
'@)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName AD01 -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

[source](https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2011/11/powershell-convert-string-to-scriptblock/)
[don't use backquote](https://get-powershellblog.blogspot.com/2017/07/bye-bye-backtick-natural-line.html)

Answer (score 0):

In windows terminal (powershell profile) I can simply click `Shift-Enter` works fine for me.

```
PS C:\xxx2021> Get-ChildItem -Include *remote* -Recurse |
>> Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending  |
>> Select-Object LastWriteTime, Name -First 25

LastWriteTime        Name
-------------        ----
12/5/2021 5:04:02 PM remote-control-car-BatteryPack-Number-2021-12-03.pdf

PS C:\xxx2021>enter code here
```

Comment: If it's not set by default, its the function `addLine` -> `Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord 'shift+enter' -Function AddLine`