# How to end a multi-line command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, multiline

This should be easy, but can't figure it out. How do I end a multi-line command in PowerShell? For example if I enter `Get-ChildItem |` and press enter then I get a `>>` prompt which I assume is to continue the command. But if I then enter `foreach{Write-Host $_.name}` and press enter I still get the `>>` prompt.

How do I say, *I'm done, run this now*? I thought it would happen when I wrote a complete command (not ending with a pipe or an unclosed bracket), but doesn't seem to. Also tried ending with a semi-colon, but that didn't help much.

Comment: You need to type an extra 'enter'...

Comment: Yup... \*facepalm\*... At least now if there are other stupid people like me they have a place to go :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter a multi-line command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command)

Comment: @bahrep I think that is a completely different question. It is talking about splitting a command over multiple lines and all the answers are about using a backtick to escape the line end.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

And right after I asked, I figured it out... Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> *twice* made it happen :)

Answer (score 19):

If you continue to get **>>** prompts after pressing **enter** twice, check your script for unterminated strings, i.e., unpaired quotes.

Comment: or unpaired braces

Answer (score 0):

Also look for missing = sign between attribute and its value, this will give you >> prompts even after pressing enter twice.