# Invoke-command specify scriptblock on the same line

Tags: powershell

I was wondering is it possible to pass a tiny script into the ScriptBlock parameter but do it all in one line?

For instance, I want to run the following 2 commands:

import-module lync
get-csuser

I can do this if I have a powershell script file and call that file explicitly. The contents of the script look like this

```
invoke-command -ComputerName mycomputer.mylab.com -ScriptBlock {
import-module lync
get-csuser
}
```

I want to be able to do the above without putting this into a temporary script file and do it on one lime. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `;` to do this. In PowerShell, the semicolon is a statement separator and allows you to use multiple statements on the same line.

```
invoke-command -ComputerName mycomputer.mylab.com -ScriptBlock { import-module lync ; get-csuser }
```

The semi-colon is among a handy set of characters that you can use to format things to your needs. Another example [is using a backtick to split a command across multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3235850/775544).

Comment: Fantastic, glad to know PS has a ; separator. Thanks so much for your quick reply! :)