# Imagemagick command in command line and windows powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd, command, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to run an imagemagick command line in my windows powershell but it does not work, if I run it in my regular command line it does work.

The command looks like this:

(I do not need the linebreaks, I just put them so that the command is more readable)

```
convert -bordercolor none -background none -gravity center ^
k1.jpg -border 5x5 ^
( k2.jpg k3.jpg k4.jpg -border 5x5 +append ) ^
( k5.jpg k6.jpg k1.jpg -border 5x5 +append ) ^
-append -border 5x5 -resize 720x480 output.png
```

I get following error if I run it in my powershell: ( I had to translate it into english)

> k2.jpg : the wording "k2.jpg" was not detected as a name of a cmdlet,
>   a function, a script file.

**Edit:**

Actually I do not need the lines breaks, I just put them so that the code is more readable, if you have a suggestion without the line breakers it is fine aswell.

Edit:

I tried Matt's suggestion like this:

```
convert --% -bordercolor none -background none -gravity center k1.jpg -border 5x5 (k2.jpg k3.jpg k4.jpg -border 5x5 +append) (k5.jpg k6.jpg k7.jpg -border 5x5 +append) -append -border 5x5 -resize 720x480 output.png
```

And I got following error/message:

> convert.exe: unable to open image '(k2.jpg': No such file or directory
>   @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2695. convert.exe: unrecognized option
>   `+append)' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/764.

Comment: Powershell uses other line-breaks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command

Comment: @D.J. thank you I did not know that, I don't really need the line breaks in my command I just put them down so that the command is more readable. After trying your suggestion I get the same error above.

Comment: That second error is not from PowerShell anymore. That is coming from convert.exe. It would appear the stop parsing parameter is working as intended now.

Comment: Try adding either a circumflex (`^`) or a backslash, or a back-tick before both `(` and `)`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks but it did not work

Comment: Oh, you **must** leave spaces **both** sides of `(` and `)`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell  hmm could you post that command please

Comment: I don't want to tread on @Matt 's toes as he has done all the hard work, so I won't post an answer. All, I'm saying is that I noticed in your question, where you say you tried Matt's suggestion, the command you tried has not got spaces both sides of the parentheses and you MUST include those - exactly as you did with the first command you showed in your question.

Comment: Great that worked

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issue is that PowerShell is trying to treat those like PowerShell syntax. `()` denotes an expression.

[There are multiple ways of handling exe's in PowerShell](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx). Depending on your intention and PowerShell version some options are more of a pain then others (Some even deprecated by more preferred methods).

The easiest thing to do with what you have shown is to use the stop parsing operator:

> The stop-parsing symbol (--%), introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0,
>       directs Windows PowerShell to refrain from interpreting input as 
>       Windows PowerShell commands or expressions.

So you could just do this instead:

```
convert --% -bordercolor none -background none -gravity center....
```

I don't have an environment to test what you are doing but perhaps you can use quotes around those arguments so PowerShell won't think of it as anything but a string.

```
"( k2.jpg k3.jpg k4.jpg -border 5x5 +append )"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I tried your second suggestion first :) unfortunatly it did not work, do I need to call on your first suggestion --% just once at the start or do I need to call it more than once?

Comment: Once at the start @utdev

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work I udpated my question with the command I used + error / message from the command line

Comment: I have to leave now, it may be too much to ask for but do you mind testing your command on your system if you can, so that I know that it is not a system error or something like that

Comment: @utdev From my answer _I don't have an environment to test what you are doing_