# How do you continue a command on the next line (not 'how do I write a multi-line command')

Tags: powershell

I know how to use back-tick to create a multi-line command in the script pane or in a PowerShell script.  This is not a question about that.  If I am in vanilla PowerShell (not ISE) and I want to type this command at the prompt:

```
Get-Command `
| Sort Name `
| Select -First 10
```

How do I move to the next line after `Get-Command` without executing it?

Comment: have you tried a backslash(\\)? not sure if it'd work, but usually a backslash is used to break a continuous line.

Comment: `.{ <# multiple lines here #> }`

Comment: [This answer in particular in the linked duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35180380/3905079) explains how to use `SHIFT ENTER`.

Comment: If you put a backtick at the end of the line, PowerShell prompts for more input. What specifically isn't working?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart So that was actually the first thing I tried but I tried it at the command prompt in ISE and it did not work.  I just assumed it would not work in vanilla PowerShell but apparently it does.  Too bad the behavior is not consistent between the two.

Comment: @briantist I did see that question but felt that it was slightly different from what I am asking.  The OP in that question is specifically asking for a charter to allow you perform line continuations.  I know the character, I am looking for a key-combination to move to the next line without executing what is at the command prompt.  The selected answer did not address that either.  I did not read the other answers below the selected answer to find the answer you mentioned.

Comment: @JasonBoyd I see the difference in the original question, but the answer to your question can still be found there, and it's highly related.

Comment: @briantist - Actually, I was thinking about opening something on meta about this. I think my question really needs to be restated as I led people astray with this: 'vanilla PowerShell (not ISE)'. The fact is I was at the console in ISE which apparently behaves differently than vanilla PowerShell. The question should really be about moving the cursor to the next line when at the console in ISE (only shift+enter works in that case).  That is different from the other question. But changing the question now would mean many of these comments would no longer make sense in the new context.

Comment: @JasonBoyd I would say just edit the question. As it happens, the answer I linked to has had some comments and it seems it applies only the ISE console anyway (or console host with PSReadLine), so it's actually still appropriate for your intended question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Powershell, SHIFT + ENTER takes you to the new line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the ISE, try putting the `|` at the end of the line before you press `Shift+Enter`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart It appears that only works in vanilla PowerShell.  Shift+Enter seems to be the only thing that works at the console in ISE.

Comment: You don't need the backtick in the ISE for line continuation since it supports multi-line input with `Shift+Enter`. But to keep from confusing the parser, you need to break the line in semantically sensible places (i.e., after a `|`).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is very similar to how you tried it:

```
Get-Command |`
Sort Name |`
Select -First 10
```

Comment: No need to use backticks in this case, see [How to enter a multi-line command?](//stackoverflow.com/a/3235993)