# How to enter a multi-line command in ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

Extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command)... How do you write a multi-line command in Powershell ISE? Backtick does not work.

I'm talking about the command prompt window `C:\>`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/fundamental/exploring-the-windows-powershell-ise -> "*Press SHIFT+ENTER to enter each line of a multiline command, and press ENTER after the last line to execute the multiline command.*"

Comment: Are you asking about the *scripting* window or the *command* window?  The backtick (`) does work in the scripting window.  For the command window, Joey's answer is correct.

Comment: http://windowsitpro.com/blog/breaking-lines-powershell-lose-backtick
If there's any white space after the backtick - a space or tab, for example - then THAT will be escaped, not the carriage return. That fact makes it very easy to mess up when you're typing a command in, with the result being improper execution and unexpected error messages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to enter multiple lines. Just <kbd>Return</kbd> will execute it.