# How to make python command line argument continue in a new line

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a python program which take a dozen input parameters, so normally I invoke it with 
`python my_script.py --inputA a --inputB b --inputC c --inputD d --inputE e --inputF f --inputG g --inputH h --inputI i --inputJ j --inputK k`

This is a long line, and it is not easy to read

I tried add `\` charactor after `--inputA a` in command line, but after return the return key, it will run, not wait for me to input another input parameter

Comment: Doesn't have anything do with python. What shell are you using?

Comment: what you can do in this case , as a parameter take a file, inside the file keep all this pair and parse the file and get the data

Comment: @rdas windows powershell

Comment: You need to use the "`" (backtick) character for line-continuation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command

Answer (score -3):

you can use  input parameter  command

param = input("Please input parameter \n")

here example :

http://en.verejava.com/?id=2022295574921

Comment: While this is valid code for when the script is taking input, it does not match the question, which is regarding flags passed in the execution command itself.