# How to list C# compile options in on multiple lines using a PowerShell Script

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm working on a project with an external API that requires me to manually compile an assembly through PowerShell. I have to manually include each of the API's references as compile options, which could end up being 5 or 6 different references. So I'd like to be able to write all of these compile options on multiple lines for readability, and thought encapsulating these instructions inside a PowerShell script would be viable.

However, PowerShell sees newlines as a separate command, so having

```
csc /target:library
/reference:xx\xx\xx\xx.dll
```

Doesn't work. It thinks /reference is supposed to be a cmdlet.

Is this kind of functionality even possible? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can - I believe even [response file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/response-file-compiler-option) expects all options on one line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backtick (`) is the [line continuation character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command) in Powershell. This should work:

```
csc /target:library `
    /reference:xx\xx\xx\xx.dll
```

It's recommended to use a space before the backtick for reliable parsing.

Comment: Thank you, I had tried this earlier but I think I had a space or something following a back tick which ended up breaking the code. Are there any other suggestions for improving readability?

Comment: That's correct - the backtick is Powershell's escape character and it's escaping the cr/lf so it has to be the last character on the line. 
For readability, you may have noticed that I indented the subsequent line to indicate it's part of the previous line.