# How to break chained .net calls into multiple lines within powershel script?

Tags: powershell, syntax

There are few answers that show different multiline tricks like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command), but nothing explains how to achieve this code format, if ever possible

```
set-content $file $fll.Replace("Long line 1", "Very Long line 1")
                      .Replace("Long line 2", "Very Long line 2")
                      .Replace("Long line 3", "Very Long line 3")
                      .Replace("Long line 4", "Very Long line 4")
                      .Replace("Long line 5", "Very Long line 5")
```

If the `Replace` above are chained in a single line - it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific code snippet posted, not just the generic case of breaking a chained .NET call across lines:

[1] Put the dot `.` after the closing parentheses. (generic case of breaking *any* .NET call across lines)

[2] Enclose the second parameter to `Set-Content` in parentheses.

```
Set-Content $file (
    $fll.Replace("Long line 1", "Very Long line 1").
        Replace("Long line 2", "Very Long line 2").
        Replace("Long line 3", "Very Long line 3").
        Replace("Long line 4", "Very Long line 4").
        Replace("Long line 5", "Very Long line 5")
)
```

Comment: does not work for me - `A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument`. And even when I added `-Value`, still - no luck

Comment: @T.S.- This is working for me. What is the output of `($PSVersionTable.PSVersion).ToString()`

Comment: @T.S. - thought you just wanted to know how to break _any_ chained .NET call. Updated the answer to be more specific to the exact question.

Comment: Now, this ^^ works! Thanks. Simple enough but just couldn't find this syntax. Will have to live with the '.' at the end