# The term '-alias' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: java, flutter, alias

keytool -list -v 
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore

i need to get SHA1, but when this code is run it will show what is in this picture[check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PcXF.jpg)
who can help me?

Comment: Hi, Here are some ideas: 1) Maybe try to put the command all on one line.  2) Looks like you're using PowerShell, but you used a Bash long line extend character "\".  Maybe try the PowerShell line extend char "`" instead. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command

Comment: Looks like you're using PowerShell, but you used a Bash long line extend character "\". Remove the "\" and put the whole command on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

open applevel build,gradle file in new window then from gradel tab on left side open android->app->signing report it will generate SHA-1 key for debug and release

Answer (score 0):

First thing go to the path of jdk and open cmd there :-
example path(May be its your path two ) : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2

Then paste the below line :-

keytool -list -v
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore

where in place of  %USERPROFILE%.android you need to put path of "debug.keystore" in my case it was :
C:\Users\wil10\.android