Poweshell syntax error for calling module with file path
I am quite new to python, but I would still like to try and run a tensorflow model.
I was stucked at the inference part, the instruction given seems like not supporting the powershell syntax interpretation.
# run from `models/`
python3 -m official.projects.unified_detector.run_inference \
--gin_file=official/projects/unified_detector/configs/gin_files/unified_detector_model.gin \
--ckpt_path=<path-of-the-ckpt> \
--img_file=<some-image> \
--output_path=<some-directory>/demo.jsonl \
--vis_dir=<some-directory>


But I am getting the error below:
at Line:2 Characters:3

--gin_file=official/projects/unified_detector/configs/gin_files/unifi ...
~
'--' The operator is missing after the unary operator.
at Line:2 Characters:3
--gin_file=official/projects/unified_detector/configs/gin_files/unifi ...
Unexpected 'gin_file=official/projects/unified_detector/configs/gin_files/unified_detector_model.gin' vocabulary primitive in operation or statement.

I tried to open up the run.inference.py to change the related directory, but I am getting the error below:
from official.projects.unified_detector import external_configurables # pylint: disable=unused-import
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'official'


I had tried to change the newline to backtick as follow:
(.venv) PS C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxx\models> # run from `models/`
>> python3 -m official.projects.unified_detector.run_inference `
>> --gin_file=official/projects/unified_detector/configs/gin_files/unified_detector_model.gin `
>> --ckpt_path=official/projects/unified_detector/ckpt `
>> --img_file=official/projects/unified_detector/image/file.jpg `
>> --output_path=official/projects/unified_detector/demo.jsonl `
>> --vis_dir=official/projects/unified_detector


what the powershell terminal returns:
file=official/projects/unified_detector/image/file.jpg `\x0a--output_path=official/projects/unified_detector/demo.jsonl `\x0a--vis_dir=official/projects/unified_detector;7614de8c-fd79-44bf-b171-971da599ac7e

with the path in the format of 'C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\ckpt' and C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\ckpt as well as forward slash variant.
Update-1:
tried to remove all the newline and backtick as shown below, works fine until I try to add in more arguments (i.e. img_file, output_path and vis_dir)
(.venv) PS C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\models> python3 -m official.projects.unified_detector.run_inference gin_file="official/projects/unified_detector/configs/gin_files/unified_detector_model.gin" ckpt_path="official/projects/unified_detector/ckpt"

Update-1.1: more arguments with path added
(.venv) PS C:\Users\xx\Desktop\xx\models>  python3 -m official.projects.unified_detector.run_inference gin_file="official/projects/unified_detector/configs/gin_files/unified_detector_model.gin" ckpt_path="official/projects/unified_detector/ckpt" img_file="official/projects/unified_detector/image/file.jpg" output_path="official/projects/unified_detector" vis_dir="official/projects/unified_detector"

error from Update-1.1:
/image/file.jpg" output_path="official/projects/unified_detector" vis_dir="official/projects/unified_detector";7614de8c-fd79-44bf-b171-971da599ac7e

I am expecting to get a powershell syntax for me to run the module with external file path input, either single line or multiple line command is ok, as long as it works.
Any help is much appreciated !!

The solution with ``` for line continuation should work in principle. There must be a different problem that you're not showing us. If you provide a concrete command line that fails (anonymize any sensitive parts) along with the resulting error message, people may be able to help you.

@mklement0 I had edited the question to include the exact error, hope that will provide more information, thanks!

P.s. searched for what the error might means, seems like related to \ usage in the powershell, but I didn't use any \ in the path.
P.s. while the error identifier at the end seems to be related to the python script itself, stating that the image file doesn't meet the script requirement, even though I am using image from the validation set.

"error from Update-1.1:" It does not look like a error message. It is part_of_your_command;some_uuid4. There are plenty reasons why only the part is shown but I have no clue why you have this UUID4


Bash example is used in the first code part. For Powershell syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235993 . So \ must be replaced with `

Fixing 1) allows you to avoid editing run.inference.py but No module named official can be met in another context too.
To overcome it the command must be run with python working directory (going simple: it is your current working directory in the terminal) that contains official module.

What happened after you changed the call to the backtick? Have you reset the changes in the run.inference.py?


General advice:
It is often beneficial to go simple first. E.g. do not use full path (as with ckpt), but place the files/folders into the working folder and verify if it works. If yes move files one-by-one and check that nothing breaks

For (1) and (3),  replacing \ with ` gives me error below:
unified_detector/testsign1.png \x0a--output_path=official/projects/unified_detector/demo.jsonl \x0a--vis_dir=official/projects/unified_detector;cf5e8ccf-d962-49f0-b06e-80a2aef2f35b

For (2), I did a copy with different file name to run the test with file path embeded, so it wont affect the original copy.
Yes, I do run the script in the current working directory which contain the official module, so I am confused with the error shown.
