# PowerShell command over multiple lines

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a batch script that looks like this:

#### Test.bat

```
@echo off

:: Starts a PowerShell session that starts a PowerShell process with administrator privileges
powershell -noprofile -command "&{$process = start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -noexit -file GetTools.ps1' -verb RunAs -PassThru;$process.WaitForExit();}"
```

I would like to split up the code inside the "&{ ... }" over multiple line for readability.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608144/how-to-split-long-commands-over-multiple-lines-in-powershell) post says that using a trailing backtick should do the trick, but when I write:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "&{`
    $process = start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -noexit -file GetTools.ps1' -verb RunAs -PassThru;`
    $process.WaitForExit();`
}"
```

...that is, I end each line with a trailing backtick, then I get the following error:

```
Incomplete string token.
At line:1 char:4
+ &{` <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (`:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncompleteString

'$process' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'$process.WaitForExit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'}"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION:**

```
powershell -noprofile -command "&{"^
    "$process = start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -noexit -file C:\Dev\Powershell\Sandbox.ps1' -verb RunAs -PassThru;"^
    "$process.WaitForExit();"^
    "}"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may try the caret `^` to indicate that the current line continues on the next one:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "&{"^
 "$process = start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -noexit -file GetTools.ps1' -verb RunAs -PassThru;"^
 "$process.WaitForExit();"^
 "}"
```

Please note also the leading space as well as the closing and opening `"` on each line.

See also *[Long commands split over multiple lines in Windows Vista batch (.bat) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-vista-dos-batch-bat-file)*.

Comment: That results in: "Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At line:1 char:4
+ &{^ <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (CloseBraceToken:TokenId) [], ParentContainsErrorRecord
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndCurlyBrace

'$process' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Try adding a space at the beginning of the following lines.

Comment: Now it works... on top of the leading space, double-quotes have to be closed before the end of line and reopened on the next line.

Comment: I got it to work, you almost had it, just need to remove the trailing backticks. :) Thanks!

Comment: I did remove them in my example... after having spotted them :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. I think this will help.

```
powershell -noprofile -command ""&{^
    $process = start-process powershell -ArgumentList '-noprofile -noexit -file GetTools.ps1' -verb
    RunAs -PassThru;^
    $process.WaitForExit();^
}""
```