# How to assign multiple lines string in Powershell Console

Tags: string, powershell, multiline

When I do enter this in powershell Console

```
$test=@'
Test
Test'@
```

And do enter several times, it keeps printing

```
>>
```

So I can never finish command.

What to do ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$test=@'
Test
Test
'@
```

The important thing to note is that the delimiters include (invisible) carriage returns. There must be one at the end of the starting tag, and one before the closing tag.

Answer (score 111):

`'@` should be first thing in the line or it is considered to be just a part of the string.

```
$test=@'
Test
Test
'@
```

This approach also works with `@"`/`"@`

Comment: the '@ must start the line, in your code it is at the end of the line

Comment: And the `"@` (or `'@`) needs to be at the very start of the final line, with nothing after it

Comment: @CJBS *with nothing after it* Can you provide reference for this claim?

Comment: @PetSerAl I recorded my thoughts incorrectly. I meant nothing *before* the `'@` or `"@` on the final line. It's possible to have a command or comment *after* the "here string" terminator.

Answer (score 17):

As per the section on [maximum line length](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/blob/master/Style-Guide/Code-Layout-and-Formatting.md#maximum-line-length) in [*The PowerShell Best Practices and Style Guide*](https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle), I would suggest “splatting” the string, like this:

```
$myStr = ("The family of Dashwood had long been settled in Sussex. Their estate was " +
              "large, and their residence was at Norland Park, in the centre of their " +
              "property, where, for many generations, they had lived in so respectable " +
              "a manner as to engage the general good opinion of their surrounding " +
              "acquaintance.")
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You are concatenating multiple strings to produce a string that does not contain any new line characters. What if you're trying to find and replace a multi-line string in another file?