# Create SQL user fails from powershell command with incorrect syntax near password field

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, powershell

I am trying to run below command from powershell script on AWS EC2 instance through SSM:

```
$Params = @{
        Comment = 'Create a SQL user'
        DocumentName = 'AWS-RunPowerShellScript'
        Targets = @(
        @{
            Key = 'InstanceIds'
            Values = @(
                "InstanceID"
            )
        })
        Parameters = @{
           commands = @(
           '$sqlConn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'
           '$userID = "testuser"'
           '$password = "testpassword"'
           '$sqlConn.ConnectionString = (Get-SSMParameterValue -Name "/ops/DbConnectionString" -WithDecryption $true).Parameters.Value'
           '$sqlConn.Open()'
           '$sqlQuery = @(
           "CREATE LOGIN [$userID] WITH PASSWORD='$password' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_EXPIRATION = ON, CHECK_POLICY = ON",
           "CREATE USER [$userID] FOR LOGIN [$userID]",
           "ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [$userID]",
           "ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [$userID]"
           )'
           '$Command = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLCommand'
           '$Command.Connection = $sqlConn'
           'foreach($query in $sqlQuery) {
            Write-Host "Command is   : $query"
            $Command.CommandText = $query
            $Reader = $Command.ExecuteReader()
            $Reader.close()
            }'
            '$sqlConn.close()'
       ) 
        }
    }
    $JsonStr = $Params | ConvertTo-Json  -Depth 4
    $FileName = 'SSMCommandTempFile-' + $(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss) + '.json'
    $FilePattern = 'file://' + $FileName
    $JsonStr | Out-File -FilePath $FileName -Encoding ASCII
    aws ssm send-command --document-name "AWS-RunPowerShellScript" --cli-input-json $FilePattern
    Remove-Item $FileName
```

But getting below error:

`... H PASSWORD='$password' MUST_CHANGE, CHECK_EXPIRATION = ON, CHECK_POLI ...`

I tried double quotes around password as well as no quotes but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Have you tried with a [multiline string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793449/how-to-assign-multiple-lines-string-in-powershell-console)  Be aware that your code is vulnerable for SQL injection. You could also try with `$($varibaleName)`

Comment: I tried it, it still give the same error `Exception calling "ExecuteReader" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near 'testpassword'."`

Comment: Print out your sqlQuery variable and validate it in SSMS, you are probably missing some quotes.

Comment: Also use `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead of `ExecuteReader()` since you are not expecting any results.

Comment: It works when I run it directly in the AWS console with `'$($password)'` But it fails when I run it from CLI tool. So something is wrong when it converts the script before running it in EC2. Will check by printing the query like you said. Thanks

Comment: had to add one more single quote around password variable to get it to work in AWS through `send command`. Something like `''$($password)''`