# Error in powershell activedirectory cmdlet

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

I've been struggling for a few days with a simple PowerShell script to create users with certain attributes for my company. The goal of the script is for users to always contain certain attributes to maintain the same structure.

Well, the error that it returns is the following:

> The term '-SamAccountName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check whether you typed the name correctly or, if you included a path, check that the name is entered correctly.

The error is repeated for each variable.

This is my code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

New-ADUser -Name (Read-Host "Input username")

-GivenName (Read-Host "Input name")

-Surname (Read-Host "Input surname")

-SamAccountName (Read-Host "Input username")

-UserPrincipalName (Read-Host "Input fqdn")
-Path "OU=Users,DC=XXXX,DC=com"
-AccountPassword(Read-Host "Input Password")
-Enabled $false
```

Even though it returns errors, the user is created in my OU Users, but I don't understand why the errors occur.

Documenting myself, I have checked that I have the active directory module installed:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

Is it possible that this error is due to the version of PowerShell I used?

The minimum version for cmdlet is 7...

As you can see, the user creates me but with all the attributes empty

```
PS C:\Users\XXXXX> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
>>

Major Minor Build Review
----- ----- ----- --------
5 1 17763 5122
```

Greetings and thank you!

Comment: Hmmm ... do you really run the code the way you show here? You know you cannot add arbitrary line breaks where you want, don't you?

Comment: If you're splitting your cmdlet in multiple lines, then you should split them with a backtick `\`` character followed by new line, and continue your cmdlet. Check this for more info - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608144/how-to-split-long-commands-over-multiple-lines-in-powershell.

Comment: Instead of using backticks what's highly error prone you should take a look at splatting!  [about_Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: Great I was able to solve it with spatting @Olaf thx!